# How to insert records using a SELECT statement?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

**Background**

I currently have a table named `Parts_list` that is structured as shown below:

[image]

_id is autoincrementing so I always provide NULL which works fine.

I would like to use a SELECT statement to populate this table but have difficulties how to write the INSERT SELECT statement.

**What I have tried**

For testing I have tried this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Parts_list VALUES 
   (null, 'My Name',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, null, null, null, null, 
    null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
    null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
    null, null, null,null, null, null)
```

and it inserts a new line without any problem.

**Problem**

However when I try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Parts_list VALUES 
(null, 'My Name',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Part_ID, null, null, null, 
 null, null, null,null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
 null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
 null, null) 
SELECT Part_ID FROM tracking_vehicles
```

where I am selecting one column and trying to insert this column, nothing happens. Do I have something wrong with my syntax?  In my example "Part_ID" is VARCHAR, which matches the data type that it is being inserted to. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

PS I also tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Parts_list 
(null, 'My Name',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Part_ID, null, 
 null, null, null, null, null,null, null, null, null, 
 null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
 null, null, null,null, null, null) 
 SELECT Part_ID FROM tracking_vehicles
```

without the word "VALUES" as I saw many examples not use that, but it doesn't work. Even when I try my first example without "VALUES" it doesn't work either so I am guessing that I need that.

Comment: @Steve Please see under my PS. I tried with out the word VALUES and it did not work

Comment: @Plutonix It is a SQL statement through sqlite. sqlite is running in a VB .NET environment. The entire statement shown above is a string statement passed into a sqlite class

Comment: @Jinx88909 I tried your idea but it doesn't like having the nulls in the SELECT part of what you are suggesting, so no success there unfortunately

Comment: @Jinx88909 Yes the nul is needed for the auto increment. As shown in the first example, my statement works when using nulls so that seems to not be the issue

Comment: But that SELECT for the Part is not just one ID, without a WHERE it should return many ids.  Hard to tell what you are up to

Comment: @Jinx88909 That is why I posted my question as SQLITE. I do know it differs in certain ways from standard SQL. Didn't I get Part_ID first in my first try? I guess I don't know how else to write it or try

Comment: @Plutonix Well I want to insert all of the values not just a single one. I want all of those values to have 2 static fields (which they all get), the timestamp and name fields. Do you know the syntax for multiple values like this?

Comment: Its rather odd to want to insert a bunch of matching empty rows, but doing it in a loop would be easier since only 1 column value changes

Comment: @Plutonix The nulls are just an example so I can try to pinpoint something that works. I can do a loop but was hoping for one nice insert select statement to speed things up.

Comment: It likely can be done, but with that many columns with a multi result SELECT it would not be simple.

Comment: @Jinx88909 Your idea works! Post as an answer if you want credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example provided [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/insert.php) I suggest you use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Parts_list (_id, table_owner, etc) 
SELECT null, 'My Name', etc 
FROM tracking_vehicles
```

List out all your columns as I've started to and then pass through all the values in the `SELECT`.

Comment: The key note for others looking at this answer in the future, is to put the names of the columns that are in the destination table